# Sort part of Array based on another array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've seen similar questions. But I'm trying to do a partial sort of an array based on values from another array.

Here is what I'm looking for:

```
let array = [
  {
    name: "Foo",
    values: [a, b, c, d]
  },
  {
    name: "Bar",
    values: [x, y]
  },
  {
    name: "FooBar",
    values: [k, l, m]
  },
  {
    name: "BarBar",
    values: [m, n]
  }
]
```

and

```
let sort = ["BarBar", "Bar"]
```

and the desired output is:

```
let desiredOutput = [
  {
    name: "BarBar",
    values: [m, n]
  },
  {
    name: "Bar",
    values: [x, y]
  },
  {
    name: "Foo",
    values: [a, b, c, d]
  },
  {
    name: "FooBar",
    values: [k, l, m]
  }
]
```

Array is sorted based on only two values and every other elements follow the same order.

I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `sort` method to first sort by condition if element exists in array and then also by index if it does exist.

```js
let array = [{name: "Foo",},{name: "Bar",},{name: "FooBar",},{name: "BarBar",}]
let sort = ["BarBar", "Bar"]

array.sort((a, b) => {
  let iA = sort.indexOf(a.name);
  let iB = sort.indexOf(b.name);
  return ((iB != -1) - (iA != -1)) || iA - iB
})

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let array = [
  {
    name: "Foo",
    values: "[a, b, c, d]"
  },
  {
    name: "Bar",
    values: "[x, y]"
  },
  {
    name: "FooBar",
    values: "[k, l, m]"
  },
  {
    name: "BarBar",
    values: "[m, n]"
  }
]

let sort = ["BarBar", "Bar"]

const sortWithAnotherArray=(arr,sortBy)=>{
  let begin =sortBy.map(e=>arr.filter(v=>v.name===e))
  let end = arr.filter(e=>sortBy.includes(e.name))
  return begin +end
}
console.log(sortWithAnotherArray(array,sort))
```